# MS Access Query SQL Sum Function

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get a sum of my count field in MS Access. In my SQL I want to have a field of sum which for each row it calculates the sum of that row's count + the next 11 rows and then so on.

```
Ref,    Count,      Yearly Sum
------------------------------
1508        3           
1507        2         
1506        5           
1505        7 
  .         .
  .         .
  .         .
1412        10
1411        11
1410        8 
1409        6
1408        1
1407        6
...         ...
```

So imagining that my query looks like the query above, I am aiming to have the sum value for the row 1508 as the sum of the counts from 1508 to 1408 (excluding 1408) and then for 1507 as the sum of counts from 1507 to 1407 (again excluding) and then so on.

I was wondering how I can address my SQL to Sum the first 12 rows in a field.

Comment: What's determining factor to decide which are the next 2 rows that should be summed with current ? do you have some sort of id or date or anything that can say - these rows are the next ones ?

Comment: @Horia I have a Ref fields which is in format of YYMM and I am aiming to get a yearly sum of the values. In my example I mentioned that I want to sum three values (as there was not enough space) but in reality I want to sum the values, lets say for the row 1508: from row 1407 to 1508. Thanks

Comment: Can you add all the columns to your question, maybe the table schema ? It would really help understand your requirement

Comment: @Horia Here is my actual query. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a self `LEFT JOIN` and use a trick that comes from your data:

```
SELECT  *, D.ref - I.ref
FROM    data AS D
        LEFT JOIN data AS I 
            ON  I.Ref <= D.Ref
            AND D.ref - I.ref < 100  /* 100 means 12 months here. for example - 1508 - 1408 = 100; < 100 means last 12 months */
ORDER BY D.ref DESC, I.ref DESC
```

`100` value here is the magic number and will define the window for you, a window of 12 months based on your `ref` column (assuming `ref` column is an integer). YOu can see here the expanded data and how join will identify last year's data. Below is the solution for you, the yearly sum:

```
SELECT  D.Ref, D.[Count], SUM(I.[Count])
FROM    data AS D
        LEFT JOIN data AS I 
            ON  I.Ref <= D.Ref
            AND D.ref - I.ref < 100  /* 100 means 12 months here. for example - 1508 - 1408 = 100; < 100 means last 12 months */
GROUP BY D.Ref, D.[Count]
ORDER BY 1 DESC ;
```

Hope it makes sense.